# how does gmail account store passwords for other sites

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Visiting https://passwords.google.com you can login to your gmail and view passwords that are managed by google.
I visited It and saw multiple passwords for other sites.

I'm wondering how my gmail knows about passwords from other sites.
I was initially thinking this was what happened when you signed up for a website with the option that says **"sign up with google"** but this can't be the case because even passwords for other email addresses are stored and passwords for sites that don't use a gmail account as the username.

Do chromium based browsers just store all password used by you in your browser. and if that is the case why does it give your gmail account access to this information.

NOTE: I'm using Brave Browser which is a chromium based alternate to Chrome that tries to block ads and trackers (I use it because It's interface is like chrome but doesn't use as much of my cpu, I had problems with chrome cpu usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en link it is written under **How Chrome saves and syncs passwords** section that

> When sync is turned on for passwords in Chrome, your passwords are saved to your Google Account.

So you can just check your settings to see if the sync is on( I think this should be available only for chrome not all chromium based browsers )?

Comment: I think What I'm seeing is passwords that were synced when I was using chrome. So chromium based browsers I believe shouldn't this feature.